# Cassandra Upsert not working on each column

Tags: cassandra, cql, upsert

I am trying to update a record in a test keyspace and table. When I upsert a record, one column value change is accepted, while the other doesn't take. (Note: I'm also not able to delete the record, despite no error message)

Observe how middle_initial does not update, while title does... What gives?

//Before

```
cqlsh:my_keyspace> SELECT * FROM user;

 last_name | first_name | middle_initial | title
-----------+------------+----------------+-------
 Rodriguez |       Mary |              Q |  null
 Rodriquez |       Mary |              Q |     O
    Nguyen |       Bill |           null |   Mr.
    Nguyen |      Wanda |           null |  Mrs.
```

//Command

```
cqlsh:my_keyspace> UPDATE user SET middle_initial = 'F', title = 'U' WHERE last_name = 'Rodriquez' AND first_name = 'Mary';
```

//After

```
cqlsh:my_keyspace> SELECT * FROM user;

 last_name | first_name | middle_initial | title
-----------+------------+----------------+-------
 Rodriguez |       Mary |              Q |  null
 Rodriquez |       Mary |              Q |     U
    Nguyen |       Bill |           null |   Mr.
    Nguyen |      Wanda |           null |  Mrs.
```

//Additional Info

```
CREATE KEYSPACE my_keyspace WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;

CREATE TABLE my_keyspace.user (
    last_name text,
    first_name text,
    middle_initial text,
    title text,
    PRIMARY KEY (last_name, first_name)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (first_name ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Comment: Can you check writetime of middle_initial column? It seems it is sometime in future.

Comment: That's exactly the reason. I did put a future write time for that value. Now to see if I can modify the write time... Thank you!

Comment: Added my comment as answer

Answer (score 2):

Manish was correct. My timestamp for middle_initial was set to a future date of 1623699999999999

To Delete the record (which was actually my goal) I did:

```
cqlsh:my_keyspace> DELETE FROM user USING timestamp 1623699999999999 WHERE first_name = 'Mary' AND last_name = 'Rodriquez';
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens generally when your column writetime is in future. You can check writetime of your column

```
SELECT WRITETIME (middle_initial) FROM my_keyspace.user WHERE last_name = 'Rodriquez' AND first_name = 'Mary';
```